# JQuery tools, overflow images from input box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, overlay

I'm creating an interface with JQuery tools, using the overlay functions.

So, I have a list of a tags that shows images in overlay

```
<a id="11" href="data/images/011.jpg">
<a id="12" href="data/images/012.jpg">
<a id="13" href="data/images/013.jpg">
<a id="14" href="data/images/014.jpg">
```

then I have an input box (without form tag) and I just want to write in there "11" and, clicking on a "show image" link, it goes in overlay
Something like this:

```
<input type="text" id="searchBox" />
<a id="searchButton" href="#">Cerca</a>
```

An alert works doing:

```
$("#searchButton").click(function(){
  alert($("#searchBox").val());
});
```

So, how can I "search" the image (trough the ID) and simulate a real click?

thanks!!!
Teo

Comment: `id` attribute values cannot begin with a number - use something like `image_11` or `image-11`

Comment: Just a note, you didn't close the a tag which might cause problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to simulate the click on the image?  In that case, it would be like

```
$('#'+$("#searchBox").val()).click()
```

Answer (score 2):

See the [web standard for element ID syntax](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#h-6.2)

> *`ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").`*

So, to be standards compliant, change markup to something like:

```
<a id="p11" href="data/images/011.jpg"></a>
<a id="p12" href="data/images/012.jpg"></a>
<a id="p13" href="data/images/013.jpg"></a>
<a id="p14" href="data/images/014.jpg"></a>
```

Javascript:

```
$("#searchButton").click(function(){ //set click event of search button
  var piclink_num = $("#searchBox").val(); //get user input which is expected to be numeric part of link ID
  $("#p" + piclink_num).trigger('click'); //trigger click event of intended link
});
```

Comment: Wow i had forgotten colons were valid - thats awesome in terms of encoding element IDs to particular application objects. Ive been using underscores and hyphens but those can get muddled sometimes when integrating certian things in different frameworks/cms's/applications - but ive never seen anyone use a colon. This makes my day haha.

Comment: prodigitalson, it's the little things, isn't it. :)

Answer (score 1):

This should invoke the click event on the appropriate link

```
$('#'+$("#searchBox").val()).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#searchButton").click(function(){
  var anchorId = $("#searchBox").val();
  alert( $("#" + anchorId).attr("href") );
});
```

This should grab the href you need.